# PayPal - Dynamic payment receiver?

Tags: paypal

I plan to create a page on my website that lets others upload games and apps they've built, then sell them via PayPal. Please forgive me if this is a simple question, I've never used PayPal for anything other than purchasing things. I need the button to dynamically change who it's sending the money to. I understand that in order to split who the money is going to, I would need to set up a business account, but if I wanted the creator to keep all of the money they charge for their virtual goods, would it be as simple as changing one of the tags within the PayPal form?

I'm experienced in PHP, SQL and Javascript, so dynamically changing any of the forms elements wouldn't be an issue, but would the payment actually finalize?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you're working with [Payments Standard](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/#wps) it would just be a matter of updating the business parameter with the email address or PayPal merchant ID of the person you want the money to go to.

This isn't the best way to do it, though, because people can see the HTML, copy it, adjust it, and submit payments that are for less than what you set the price at.

In order to protect that sort of stuff you could generate your button code using the [Button Manager API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/button-manager/integration-guide/NVP/ButtonMgrOverview/), or better yet, go with [Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/#ec) and the [Permissions API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/permissions-service/integration-guide/PermissionsAbout/) (or manually granting permissions) so you can make API calls on behalf of 3rd party users.

My [PHP class library for PayPal](http://www.angelleye.com/product/php-class-library-paypal/) would make this pretty simple for you.